# How to map a patch method over an action with detail=False in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, nested-views, nested-urls, django-viewsets

I am building an API with Django and Django Rest Framework

I have the following endpoint:
**host/products/** pointing to a **ModelViewSet**, so I have a CRUD working for the specified model.

Also, I define an extra action for a nested model called **config** with the following code:

```
@action(detail=False, methods=['get', 'post'])
def config(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        return super().list(request, *args, **kwargs)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        return super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

The created URL is:
**host/products/config/**

At this URL I can create and list objects in the **second specified model**

The problem is that I want to include **PATCH** and **DELETE** methods for the nested URL, I mean:
host/products/config/**detail**/

I try to do something like this:

```
@action(detail=True)
@config.mapping.patch
def update_config(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return super().update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

But of course, it does not work...

How can I map details action over another action in the same viewset?

**The complete code is the following:**

```
class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

def get_permissions(self):
    ''' Assign permissions based on action. '''
    if self.action in ['suggestions']:
        permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    else:
        permission_classes = [AllowAny] # [IsAdminUser | IsDevUser]
    return [permission() for permission in permission_classes]

def get_queryset(self):
    ''' Return queryset based on action. '''
    if self.action == 'config':
        # Return product details
        return ProductDetails.objects.filter(active=True)
    else:
        # Return active products
        return Product.objects.filter(active=True)

def get_serializer_class(self):
    ''' Return serializer based on action. '''
    if self.action == 'suggestions':
        return SurveySerializer
    elif self.action == 'config':
        return ProductDetailModelSerializer
    else:
        return ProductModelSerializer

@action(detail=False, methods=['get', 'post'])
def config(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        return super().list(request, *args, **kwargs)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        return super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)

@action(detail=True)
@config.mapping.patch
def update_config(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return super().update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I think it would be better to just isolate this patch operation into a different ModelViewSet class.